# spread object and add flag node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, spread-syntax

Here is my code:

```
let collection = database.collection('documents')
let savedDocumentsCollection = database.collection('savedDocuments')
let doc = await collection.find().toArray()
let saved_documents = await savedDocumentsCollection.find({username: req.session.username}).toArray()

let document_ids = []
for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
  document_ids.push(doc[i].id)
}

for (var x = 0; x < saved_documents.length; x++) {
  for(let val of document_ids) {
    if (val == saved_documents[x].id) {
        doc = {
          ...doc,
          saved: true
        }
        // console.log(true)
      } else {
        doc = {
          ...doc,
          saved: false
        }
        // console.log(false)
    }
  }
}

console.log(doc)
```

to sum it up, what it does it get the data inside collection `documents` and `savedDocuments`. What I am trying to do is compare the id's of both collections to each other, and if they both exist, then spread the current `doc` object and add the flag `saved: true` to it, and if it doesn't exist in `savedDocuments` then add flag `saved: false` to it. However, when I log `console.log(doc)`, my results look like this:

```
    '0': {
    _id: new ObjectId("635f3c3d79dffde472e69287"),
    course_code: 'xxxxx',
    name_of_document: 'doc 1',
    name_of_s: 'COMPANY',
    url: 'url',
    uploadedBy: 'John.doe@gmail.com',
    date: 2022-10-31T03:08:45.123Z,
    id: '2ac3c'
  },
  '1': {
    course_code: 'xxxxx',
    name_of_document: 'doc 2',
    name_of_s: 'COMPANY',
    url: 'url',
    uploadedBy: 'John.doe@gmail.com',
    date: 2022-10-31T03:14:40.722Z,
    id: 'fursr'
  },
  saved: false
}
```

as you can see, it only adds one `saved: false` flag there, not even within the `doc` root. There is about 10 documents in there that you don't see here, so rest assured about 5 have matching id's, and you can see I tested it by logging `true` or `false` as well, and watched it happen live. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `let doc = await collection.find().toArray()` therefore `doc` is an array. It's not the *current* doc object. That would be `saved_documents[x]`. Or maybe you meant to iterate over `doc`. Whatever it is, it's not what you're doing. Moreover, doesn't really sound like you need to spread it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code constructs a Set containing the ids of the saved documents, enabling constant-time checking whether a given ID is saved.

The code then enumerates all the documents and configures the saved property according to presence in the Set.

Time complexity is therefore O(N).

Does this do what you want?

```js
let allDocuments = [{ id: '0', name: 'foo' }, { id: '1', name: 'bar' }]
let savedDocuments = [{ id: '1' }]

const addSavedMetadata = (all, saved) => {
  const savedSet = saved.reduce((acc, {id}) => acc.add(id), new Set)
  all.forEach((d) => d.saved = savedSet.has(d.id))
  return all
}

console.log(addSavedMetadata(allDocuments, savedDocuments))
```

Comment: `saved.reduce((acc, {id}) => acc.add(id), new Set)` -> simpler to express as `new Set(saved.map(x => x.id))`

Comment: Great observation!